# How put static initial sprite and after give a random movement on pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

I need to create a platform that can move through the technique of scrolling. 
This platform should have in the start 8 static bases that will contain initial 8 robots over. These robots must move randomly in any direction (up, down, right, left) pixel by pixel after to press F1. 
Right now I have the system running and generate scrolling platform by reading a sprite. 
But i dont know to do  is to put the 8 bases at the beginning with robots initialized over the base, and when i press F1, robots, starting to move in any direction of the platform.

Example: Robots moving after to press F1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGnGL.png

This is the sprite:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zAL0.png

Thats is my code with the scrolling platform.

```
import os, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# game constants
SCREENRECT = Rect(0, 0, 1760, 880)

def imgcolorkey(image, colorkey):
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image

def load_image(filename, colorkey = None):
    filename = os.path.join(filename)
    image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
    return imgcolorkey(image, colorkey)

class SpriteSheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.sheet = load_image(filename)
    def imgat(self, rect, colorkey = None):
        rect = Rect(rect)
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert()
        image.blit(self.sheet, (0, 0), rect)
        return imgcolorkey(image, colorkey)
    def imgsat(self, rects, colorkey = None):
        imgs = []
        for rect in rects:
            imgs.append(self.imgat(rect, colorkey))
        return imgs

class Arena:
    speed = 2
    def __init__(self):
        w = SCREENRECT.width
        h = SCREENRECT.height
        self.tileside = self.oceantile.get_height()
        self.horizontal = self.oceantile.get_width()
        self.counter = 0
        self.ocean = pygame.Surface((w, h + self.tileside)).convert()
        self.oceantwo = pygame.Surface((w + self.horizontal, h)).convert()
        for x in range(w/self.tileside):
            for y in range(h/self.tileside + 1):
                self.ocean.blit(self.oceantile, (x*self.tileside, y*self.tileside))
        for y in range(h/self.horizontal):
            for x in range(h/self.horizontal):
                self.oceantwo.blit(self.oceantile, (x*self.horizontal, y*self.horizontal))        
    def increment(self):
        self.counter = (self.counter - self.speed) % self.tileside
    def decrement(self):
        self.counter = (self.counter + self.speed) % self.tileside

    def rightmove(self):
        self.counter = (self.counter + self.speed) % self.horizontal

    def leftmove(self):
        self.counter = (self.counter - self.speed) % self.horizontal


def main():
    pygame.init()

    # set the display mode
    winstyle = 0
    bestdepth = pygame.display.mode_ok(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, 32)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((792, 440), winstyle, bestdepth)

    # load images, assign to sprite classes
    # (do this before the classes are used, after screen setup)
    spritesheet = SpriteSheet('sprite.png')

    Arena.oceantile = spritesheet.imgat((10, 37, 44, 44))

    # decorate the game window
    pygame.display.set_caption('press UP, DOWN, ESC, or Q')

    # initialize game groups
    all = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()

    # initialize our starting sprites
    arena = Arena()

    # to help understand how scrolling works, press ESC
    clip = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while 1:

        # get input
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                    pygame.display.flip()
                    clip = not clip
                elif event.key == K_q:
                    return

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            arena.decrement()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            arena.increment()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
            arena.rightmove()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
            arena.leftmove()




        # update all the sprites
        all.update()

        # draw the scene
        if clip:
            screen.blit(arena.ocean, (0, 0), (0, arena.counter, SCREENRECT.width, SCREENRECT.height))
        else:
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(arena.ocean, (0, arena.tileside-arena.counter))
        all.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

How do I do that? 
Someone could help me? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ahem, what about python's `random` module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

> how to put the static initial images (bases and robots) on the field

I suggest to create separate classes for them inherited from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. So every robot and base will have a `rect` property which would describe sprite's dimensions and position. Then you could set random coordinates to those rects.

```
robot = Robot()
robot.rect = (random.randint(0, MAX_X), random.randint(0, MAX_Y), robot_width, robot_height)
```

Please refer to pygame's "chimp" tutorial about using sprites.

Comment: Thanks you Anton Melnikov for rhe random guide, but how i can to put the static initial images (bases and robots) on the field??

Comment: You get a random randint, or random integer, and then you put them on those positions. So you create a new sprite with x equaling `random.randint(1, SCREENRECT.width)` and y equaling `random.randint(1, SCREENRECT.height)`